# Yocto/Bitbake build task default execution order

Tags: yocto, bitbake

In what order are Yocto's "Normal Recipe Build Tasks" executed by default? Is there a list in text format in the reference manual? Or is it available elsewhere?

The Normal recipe build tasks such as `do_fetch`, `do_unpack`, etc is found the [Yocto reference manual](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/ref-manual/tasks.html#normal-recipe-build-tasks) but says nothing about the order.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to generate a list of tasks which have to be executed upfront. The next best thing to what you are looking for is most likely the file `log.task_order` which can be found under `<your_build_directory>/tmp/work/...` **after** you built a certain recipe.

You can find *all* available `log.task_order` files by running

```bash
$ find <your_build_directory> -name "log.task_order"
```

If you are looking for a certain *recipe* better use

```bash
$ find <your_build_directory> -name "log.task_order" | grep <recipe_name>
```

For example if I want to see all the tasks which were executed for building *u-boot-tools* I run the following from my build directory:

```bash
$ find . -name "log.task_order" | grep u-boot-tools
./tmp/work/x86_64-linux/u-boot-tools-native/1_2021.07-r0/temp/log.task_order
$ cat ./tmp/work/x86_64-linux/u-boot-tools-native/1_2021.07-r0/temp/log.task_order
do_fetch (31716): log.do_fetch.31716
do_unpack (46850): log.do_unpack.46850
do_prepare_recipe_sysroot (46851): log.do_prepare_recipe_sysroot.46851
do_patch (46901): log.do_patch.46901
do_deploy_source_date_epoch (46980): log.do_deploy_source_date_epoch.46980
do_configure (47005): log.do_configure.47005
do_compile (47032): log.do_compile.47032
do_install (49251): log.do_install.49251
do_populate_sysroot (49265): log.do_populate_sysroot.49265
```

Looking at the file with `cat` lists the tasks in the order they were executed.
Note that this **only** lists the tasks that have been tried so far. In case the recipe was built successfully this includes *all* tasks but if it fails only the tasks up to the failing one are listed.